# TypeError: Object of type 'Column' is not JSON serializable

Tags: json, python-3.x, typeerror

TypeError: Object of type 'Column' is not JSON serializable

What could this error possibly mean ?

test_respnse is a Json file which I am trying to convert into a dictionary.

```
 test_response = json.dumps(test_response)
```

Contents of test_response :

```
{
   "req_type":1,
   "date":"2021-02-21",
   "team1":{
      "name":"Everton FC",
      "player1":"Chris Gunter",
      "player2":"Matteo Darmian",
      "player3":"Ragnar Klavan",
      "player4":"Jan Vertonghen",
      "player5":"Joshua King",
      "player6":"Jordan Ayew",
      "player7":"Charlie Austin",
      "player8":"Simon Mignolet",
      "player9":"Stefano Sensi",
      "player10":"Samuel Bastien",
      "player11":"Gareth Barry",
   },
   "team2":{
      "name":"Crystal Palace FC",
      "player1":"Vincent Kompany",
      "player2":"Kieran Trippier",
      "player3":"Trent Alexander-Arnold",
      "player4":"Ben Davies",
      "player5":"Eddie Nketiah",
      "player6":"Lukas Nmecha",
      "player7":"Michael Obafemi",
      "player8":"Hugo Lloris",
      "player9":"Victor Moses",
      "player10":"Rolando Aarons",
      "player11":"Dean Whitehead",
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you also post the contents of the test_response

Comment: I found the error. There was an extra comma present at the end of a data item inside ths Json i.e. after the 11-th player of each team. Thus it gave error. Although I dont really know why though.

Answer (score 0):

The current Json looks like

```
{
   "req_type":1,
   "date":"2021-02-21",
   "team1":{
      "name":"Everton FC",
      "player1":"Chris Gunter",
      "player2":"Matteo Darmian",
      "player3":"Ragnar Klavan",
      "player4":"Jan Vertonghen",
      "player5":"Joshua King",
      "player6":"Jordan Ayew",
      "player7":"Charlie Austin",
      "player8":"Simon Mignolet",
      "player9":"Stefano Sensi",
      "player10":"Samuel Bastien",
      "player11":"Gareth Barry",
   },
   "team2":{
      "name":"Crystal Palace FC",
      "player1":"Vincent Kompany",
      "player2":"Kieran Trippier",
      "player3":"Trent Alexander-Arnold",
      "player4":"Ben Davies",
      "player5":"Eddie Nketiah",
      "player6":"Lukas Nmecha",
      "player7":"Michael Obafemi",
      "player8":"Hugo Lloris",
      "player9":"Victor Moses",
      "player10":"Rolando Aarons",
      "player11":"Dean Whitehead",
   }
}
```

There is an extra comma present after the last data item i.e. the 11-th player of the "team1" and "team2". Thus if we remove the comma, the error gets resolved since the Json is syntactically now.

After removal ths Json looks like:

```
{
   "req_type":1,
   "date":"2021-02-21",
   "team1":{
      "name":"Everton FC",
      "player1":"Chris Gunter",
      "player2":"Matteo Darmian",
      "player3":"Ragnar Klavan",
      "player4":"Jan Vertonghen",
      "player5":"Joshua King",
      "player6":"Jordan Ayew",
      "player7":"Charlie Austin",
      "player8":"Simon Mignolet",
      "player9":"Stefano Sensi",
      "player10":"Samuel Bastien",
      "player11":"Gareth Barry"
   },
   "team2":{
      "name":"Crystal Palace FC",
      "player1":"Vincent Kompany",
      "player2":"Kieran Trippier",
      "player3":"Trent Alexander-Arnold",
      "player4":"Ben Davies",
      "player5":"Eddie Nketiah",
      "player6":"Lukas Nmecha",
      "player7":"Michael Obafemi",
      "player8":"Hugo Lloris",
      "player9":"Victor Moses",
      "player10":"Rolando Aarons",
      "player11":"Dean Whitehead"
   }
}
```